# How can I control flv embedded video using external buttons?

Tags: flash, video-streaming, flv, flash-video

I am not new to Flash but I have not properly used it for sometime, a lot has changed and as such i am unable to figure this out.

I have embedded a flv video into my timeline, it uses the flv playback component to play and the SteelExternalAll.swf skin. I would like to control this flv using buttons that I have created that are postioned next to the video player. Ideally, these buttons would be thumbnails, similar to chapter thumbnails on DVDs and would serve a very similar function. As these thumbnail buttons are always present, I want them to change while the movie plays, I think a border around the currently playing would suffice.

The video is nearly 3 mins long, I have made cue points from Sorenson Squeeze.

What is the best way to do this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: The embedded tag is not appropriate to this question - it refers to "embedded systems".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FLVPlayback` dispatches a [cuePoint event](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#event:cuePoint) when the player reaches a `cuePoint`. Listen to this event and change the border of the appropriate button in the event handler.

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew it was something like that.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Like Amarghosh say- cuePoint event is the best way.